# I Can't stop functions from being called when I don't want them to

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to make a Python listing program that can read, remove and append lines onto a notepad located in my documents folder on my computer. but it involves many user defined functions that call each other.

```
def main():
    print("To Add, Type A.\nTo Read, Type B")
    c = input(">>>_ ").lower()
    if c == 'a':
        addline()
        pass readout()
    if c == 'b':
        readout()
        pass addline()
main()

def addline():
    with open(r'C:\Users\MI\Documents\PyLists\A\AList.txt', 'a+') as f:
        f_contents = f.read()
        addlyne = input('Add A Line >>>_ ')
        f.write(addlyne + '\n')
addline()

def readout():
    with open(r'C:\Users\MI\Documents\PyLists\B\BList.txt', 'r') as 
        f_contents = f.read()
        print(f_contents)
        f.close()
readout()
```

I'm aware that using "pass" won't do anything but I wan't you guys to literally see what I don't want being called when a certain action is taken.

Comment: so what is your actual issue?

Comment: Why are you calling every function immediately after you define it?

Comment: If `pass readout()` was an actual thing that would actually do what you want, what would it do? Not call `readout`? If so, simply removing the `pass` lines would do the job. Prevent later calls to `readout` from executing? Your program probably shouldn't contain those later calls at all; it's not clear why you even put them in in the first place.

Comment: What is the program doing? What do you want it to do? Exactly how do those things differ? A good question goes beyond code to include a description of desired and actual behavior, and how the two differ.

Answer (score 0):

You should be designing your functions so that you aren't calling anything you don't want in the first place. If you want to write something to a file, the function called should do that, and precisely that

```
# The line arg here comes from user input
def add_line(path=None, line):
    # Maybe you'll want a default path unless a user wants to append to a different function
    if not path:
        path = 'C://path/to/file.txt'

    # Open in append mode
    with open(path, 'a') as fh:
        fh.write(line)
        # If you want to see something was written
        print("Wrote %s to file" % line)

# Add arg in case a user wants multiple lines
def read_line(path=None, num_lines=0):

    if not path:
        path = 'C://path/to/file.txt'

    with open(path) as fh:
        lines = fh.readlines()

    # Convert lines to a string here
    if num_lines >= len(lines):
        print('\n'.join(lines)
    else:
        print('\n'.join(lines[:(-1 * abs(num_lines))])


def main():
    input_path = input("What file do you want to edit? (may be left blank)")

    user = input("What do you want to do (add/read)?")

    if user.lower().strip()=="add":
        line = input("Type what you want to add (one line)")
        add_line(path=input_path.strip(), line)

    elif user.lower().strip()=="read":
        read_line(path=input_path.strip())

    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid input, expected read or write")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The `strip()` method will remove leading and trailing whitespace, that way you don't get extra characters that *could* cause issues. The user has the option to leave it blank so you can hard-code a default file path if you want

## Edit:

Changed the num_lines argument so that it takes only positive arguments (and will convert negatives)